# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\Student' not found although in the page i can access the methods of the class

Tags: php

Here is the code

```
<?php
include_once '../vendor/autoload.php';
use App\Student;
use App\Connection;
/*echo'<pre>';
      var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';*/
$student = new Student();
$student-> set($_POST);
echo "success";
$student-> store();
```

I can access the Student class and its methods but when uses this page to insert data show the error message in the title.Any quick answer will b highly appreciated.

Thanks 
Mizan

Comment: error seems clear.

Comment: still exist!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Check your autoload config, maybe you can call `new Student()` and you dont need `use App\Student;` if autoload is pointing to App directory.

Comment: problem already solved i made capital "PSR-4" instead of "psr-4" and hence autoload was not working. thanks for replying.